# Can I develop an Adobe AIR application without Flash Builder?

Tags: air, flash-builder

Can i develop an Adobe AIR application without Flash Builder?

I want to run it from command line. If you have any example please share with me.

Comment: I personally use FlashDevelop and have for a long time. http://www.flashdevelop.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash Develop  is the best open source tool .

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Flash Develop](http://www.flashdevelop.org) as an alternative to Flash Builder, which is opensource / free.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need the Flex SDK which is available free of charge [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html). This means you need to hook it up with an IDE of your choice. The flip side is you won't have any debugger to help you along.

Note, Adobe offers free licenses of FlashBuilder for students and unemployed professionals too! See [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/free/).